# Is there a space efficent way to store and retrieve the order of a dataset?

Tags: c, data-structures, embedded, bit-manipulation

Here's my problem. I have a set of 20 objects stored in memory as an array. I want to store a second piece of data that defines an order for the objects to be displayed.

The simplest way to store the order is as an array of 20 unsigned integers, each of which is 5 bits (aka 0-31). The position of the object in the output list would be defined by the number stored in this array at the same index as the object in it's array.

But.. I know from statistics that there are only 20! (that's 20 factorial), ways to arrange these objects. 
This could be stored in 62 bits, since 2^62 > 20!

I'm currently using 100 bits to store the same information.

So my question is this: Is there a space efficient way to store ORDER as a sequence of bits?

I have some addition constraints as well. This will run on an embedded device, so I can't use any huge arrays or high level math functions. I would need a simple iterative method.

Edit: Some clarification on why this is necessary. Say for example the objects are pictures, and they're stored in ROM (aka they can't be moved around). Now lets say I want to keep track of what order to display the images in, and i'm going to update that order every second. My device has 1k of storage with wear leveling, but each bit in the storage can only be written 1000 times before it becomes unreliable. If I need 1kb to store the order, than my device will only work for 1000 seconds. If I need 0.1kb, it will work for 10k seconds, and so on. Thus the devices longevity will be inversely proportional to the number of bits I need to update every cycle.

Comment: When you store one of the 20! orders, you also need to attach some meaning to how order n arranges the elements and the code to compute a permutation from an order n would certainly outweigh the data bits you saved. How much memory do you have that you worry so much about 4 bytes of data more or less? Please tell us something about the algorithms run on that order data. There is no silver-bullet data structure, so it'll greatly depend on what you need order for, I think.

Comment: Is ordering defined for the elements of your data set? In other words, is there a way to sort them?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If he's this finicky about 38 bits to save, a fully-featured sorting algorithm is probably waaaay to space-expensive.

Comment: If there's exactly 20 items to sort you could ignore one of them, so that's 5 bits you can save!

Comment: No they can't be sorted. The reason it has to be like this is that the objects will be constant and the order will have to change constantly. I'm going to write the order to flash, so less bits = longer lifespan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [representation of permutation of integer in bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396853/representation-of-permutation-of-integer-in-bits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the order in a single 64-bit value `x`:

- For the first choice, 20 possibilities, compute the index as `x % 20` and update `x` as `x /= 20`,
- For the next choice, only 19 possibilities, compute `x % 19` and update `x` as `x /= 19`.
- Continue this process 17 more times and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a partial solution to my own question. Assuming I start at the left side of the order array, for every move right there are fewer remaining possibilities for the position value. The number of possibilities is 20,19,18,etc. I can take advantage of this by populating the order array in a relative fashion. The first index will place a value in the order array. There are 20 possibilities so this takes 5 bits. Placing the next value, there are only 19 position available (still 5 bits). Proceeding though the whole array. The bits-required is now 5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,0. So that gets me down to 69 bits, much better.

There's still some "wasted" precision in each of the values, since for example the first position can store 32 possible values, even though there are only 20. I'm not sure how to deal with this, but I think will have something to do with carrying a remainder from one calculation to the next..

Comment: But as someone pointed out, any space saved will be dwarfed by the additional space required to store a program that reads these values. It's an interesting theoretical question mind.

Comment: You are on your way to re-invent arithmetic coding.